# Bug in method for condensing ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to write a method in Java that will condense an ArrayList of Strings. For example, if we had an ArrayList that consisted of Strings `["0", "1", "2", "3"]`, the `ArrayListMethods.condense(["0", "1", "2", "3"])` would alter the ArrayList to be `["01", "23"]`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListMethods
{
  public static void condense(ArrayList<String> array){
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
            array.get(i) += array.get(i + 1);
            array.remove(i + 1);
        }
  }
}
```

I am getting an error, but I am not sure why.

Nevermind, issue resolved. I rewrote the code like this:

```
public static void condense(ArrayList<String> array){
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size() - 1; i++){
            String one = array.get(i);
            String two = array.get(i+1);
            String both = one+two;
            array.set(i, both);
            array.remove(i + 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `i < array.size()` and `i + 1` means that you address an element beyond the range of the `ArrayList` (ie `i` can be greater than the actually number of elements in the array list).  Personally, I might use a temporary `ArrayList` instead

Comment: Probably something to do with the fact that the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable at `array.get(i) += array.get(i + 1);`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Isn't ```array.get(i)``` a variable?

Comment: @ap No. `array.get(i)` isn't a variable.

Comment: It's a value, not a variable. It doesn't quite work like an array e.g. a[i] += a[i+1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure to always have an even count of elements you could do something like:

```
public static void condense(ArrayList<String> array){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
        array.set(i, array.get(i)+array.get(i + 1));
        array.remove(i + 1);
    }
}
```

A better way would but be something like:

```
public static void condense2(List<String> list){
    int groupSize = 2;
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();        
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += groupSize) {
        result.add(String.join("", list.subList(i,Math.min(i + groupSize, list.size()))));            
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

With the second aproach you are not limited to just concatenate only two strings, by changing the groupSize you can achieve something like `["012", "345", "6"]` from the input of `["0","1","2","3","4","5","6"]`

Answer (score 1):

array.get(i) isn't a variable, it's a method call that returns `String` in your case.
You can't assign anything to it.

You probably want something like `array.set(i, array.get(i + 1))`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I'm getting an ```IndexOutOfBoundsException```. Besides, I'm not sure that would do what I want if it worked. I want to concatenate consecutive Strings in the ArrayList. This would just set each String to the value of the next one.

Comment: `array.set(i, array.get(i) + array.get(i + 1))` would be the correct code

Comment: You are probably getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because you need to account for odd sized lists (3,5,7,9,11, etc). I'm sure you can figure out that edge case.